# How to get assigned a dynamic html tag text to a variable in ruby

Tags: html, ruby, variables, dynamic, automation

```html
<select id="recentsearchs" name="searchname">
    <option value="select recent item">select recent item </option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

From the above html code, I need to get option tag texts(Apple, Orange, Banana) to be assigned to a variable

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What exactly is your problem? Would you mind elaborating on what you try to achieve and what your code looks like?

Comment: @spickermann Suppose, Consider Google Search as an example. I need to select the recent search from the dropdown of recent search list. Which is dynamic right?. So, How can I get that recent searched string & assign to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this select snippet in your ruby code, not in `view` you can parse it with `nokogiri` gem

```rb
select = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(
'<select id="recentsearchs" name="searchname">
   <option value="select recent item">select recent item </option>
   <option>Apple</option>
   <option>Orange</option>
   <option>Banana</option>
</select>'
)

options = select.css('select option:nth-child(1)~option').map(&:content)
```

```rb
# output

[
    [0] "Apple",
    [1] "Orange",
    [2] "Banana"
]
```